# GWT 2.7 compiler doesn't generate cache.html files

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

The GWT 1.6.4 compiler created files like
7AEDCB61FCE68F031FDE2B8B2B0DD85C.cache.html

After upgrading to GWT 2.7, cache.html files are no longer generated in my project. Instead .js files are generated, e.g.
46D172E45CA94222554BE5B5DBFAA7AC.cache.js

With these files none of the GWT widgets are presented in my website.
The cache.html files are missing when I run the GWT compiler from Intellij or from Eclipse. I ran the GWT compiler with log level DEBUG and didn't see anything in the result to indicate why cache.html files were not created.
Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

In GWT 2.7, the default linker has changed from `std` to `xsiframe`, hence the change in the file names; but this change alone is unrelated to the application not working. Also, the `std` (IFrameLinker) and `xs` (XSLinker) linkers have been deprecated, as the `xsiframe` linker combines the best of both **and** supports SuperDevMode (and SuperDevMode is turned on by default)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I added a line to my .gwt.xml file to use the std linker ( <add-linker name="std"/>) and then ran the GWT compiler. Now the .cache.html files are again being created. So I guess xsiframe linker is the problem. I wonder if this is a bug or a feature of the xsiframe linker.

Comment: The xsiframe linker generates `*.cache.js`, this is just how it works. That shouldn't change how your app behaves. As I said, you shouldn't use the `std` linker; if you have assumptions about having `*.cache.html` files generated, then change your assumptions to expect `*.cache.js`.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas ... you're right. I tried again with xsiframe linker and the app works with cache.js instead of cache.html files. Don't know why it didn't work earlier.